# update columns and multiple updates by checkBox the columes

Tags: c#, checkbox, sql-update, multiple-columns

This feels like it shouldn't be an easy one. How do I update my sql server table by checkBox with the columns name ;

```
DROP TABLE #indebtedness
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[indebtedness](
[Subscriber_No] [bigint] NULL,
[Subscriber_Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Last_Deact_Date] [date] NULL,
[allocated] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
[collected] [numeric](18, 3) NOT NULL,
[ID_No] [bigint] NULL,
```

I'm using desktop application with c# code I look for have to checkBox to update the column from dataGridView

i use something like this code to update my database

```
int countSuccess = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    // INSERT command:
    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UPDATE indebtedness SET autodialtype=@autodialtype,autodial=@autodial,autodate=@autodate,lastdate=@lastdate,lastcall_case=@lastcall_case WHERE  Subscriber_No=@Subscriber_No and company_name=@company_name and indebtedness_name=@indebtedness_name", con))
    {
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company_name", company_name.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@indebtedness_name", indebtedness_name.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subscriber_No", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@autodialtype", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@autodial", "Called");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@autodate", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastcall_case", "AutoDial");
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastdate", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());

        int numUpd = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        countSuccess += numUpd;

        //com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

MessageBox.Show($"Successfully UPDATED {countSuccess} of {dataGridView1.Rows.Count} rows");
```

[image: from loke like]

I just want to update the column that I check for update only

Comment: Set parameter using `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Your_param"` param_val);. Set rest of parameters `Null` . In Stored Procedure Update only `Non Null` parameters

Comment: @SushantYelpale i didn't understand how to check the checkbox first than update the column where the checkbox is true

Comment: are you using desktop Application?

Comment: @SushantYelpale Yes

Comment: what have you tried till now to get the checkbox Value. you can get checkbox checked propery in codebehind as `checkbox_name.Checked` Edit question accordingly

Comment: @SushantYelpale if (checkBox1.Checked == true){ }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203012/discussion-between-sushant-yelpale-and-ahmed-alkhteeb).

Comment: @SushantYelpale im there